# Causes of hexagonal shape of Saturn's jet stream

Tags: astrophysics, planets, aerodynamics, atmospheric-science, solitons

NASA has just shown a more detailed picture of the hexagonal vortex/storm on Saturn:

> http://www.ibtimes.com/nasa-releases-images-saturns-hexagon-mega-storm-may-have-been-swirling-centuries-1496218
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_hexagon

Is that theoretically understood what is the cause behind this eye-catching nontrivial, regular yet not circular, shape? If so, what is the cause? I expect some explanation in terms of "nonlinear equations" of "mathematical physics" and "solitons".

P.S. (added a day after this question and the first answer was posted): On [my blog](http://motls.blogspot.com/2013/12/hexagonal-shape-of-saturns-vortex.html?m=1) where I posted the same question, people came up with some articles and phrases like "Rossby waves" and "resonance of latitude-dependence Coriolis frequency".

Comment: I don't think solitons are relevant for this phenomenon

Comment: Interesting, can you use the same method to create pentagons and octagons?

Comment: I've already answered this question [here](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/1689/96), though I won't repost it as hdhondt already has addressed the issue with the same reference.

Answer (score 19):

I doubt if anyone has come up with a complete explanation, but some laboratory simulations have created similar patterns. They happen if the central and surrounding areas in a flat, circular disk of fluid have different velocities. Emily Lakdawalla at The Planetary Society covers it at [this site](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2010/2471.html). She also explains how other patterns (triangles & heptagons) form under similar circumstances.

Comment: The full paper by Aguiar, Read, Wordsworth, Salter and Yamazaki is here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103509004382 .  It looks like they did a linear stability analysis of certain solutions of the barotropic vorticity equation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barotropic_vorticity_equation describing the flow in the atmosphere, which then motivated their experiments.

Comment: The experimental pictures are interesting - the hexagon arises because it's a circle being squeezed by 6 other potatoes around it. That could make sense as an approach to qualitatively explain the Z6 symmetry and why the solution is stable.