# Saturn's Hexagon

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, planets, solar-system

I am currently trying to understand the formation or indeed the explanation as to why the hexagonal north polar vortex on Saturn is exactly that: Hexagonal.

I understand that the most prominent explanation are due to very large longitudinal gradients in the velocity of atmospheric winds.

To that end, I wonder if anyone could point me to recent advances in reseasrch in this area, or references to other pdfs on the web would be most welcome.

Comment: Related: [http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89076/](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89076/)

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks, i figured it could have been asked before but I'd asked before checking. The paper by Aguiar, Read, Wordsworth, Salter and Yamazaki is exactly what I'm looking for. Many thanks!