# What causes Saturn's hexagon hurricane?

Tags: atmospheric-science, planets, solar-system, vortex, weather

Recently, Tien Nguyen JPL Fellow - Chief Engineer at NASA Jet Propulsion Laboratory, did share this photo that says "Cassini catches an awesome glimpse of Saturn’s north pole hurricane"

[image]

I quote a search result about Earth "When warm moist air over the water rises, it is replaced by cooler air. The cooler air will then warm and start to rise. ... If there is enough warm water, the cycle will continue and the storm clouds and wind speeds will grow causing a hurricane to form"

Can anyone explain to me what causes Saturn's hexagon hurricane?

Comment: It _looks_ kind of like a hurricane on Earth, but that does not mean it is caused in the same way since, well, Saturn isn't Earth. Yes, imprecise language perhaps.

Comment: I know something about Saturn, like gravity, temperature, and ... but what I know can not help me to compare.

Comment: Search term: "polar vortex."

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89076/2451